# expect interpreter equivalent for pexpect

Tags: python, expect, pexpect

Is there an equivalent to `expect`'s `interpreter` command for `pexpect`.

In `expect` `interpreter` gives the user access to a `tcl` repl with the current variable scopes.  I would like to give my user access to a `python` repl (preferably `ipython`) with the current variable scopes, it would be great for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to do this so far is a clunky hack:

1. `breakpoint()` will put the user into a pdb debugging session
2. user enters `p varname` for user to check if the current variables are in scope (I typically find that they aren't, because I'm somewhere in the ipython internals).  If not in scope then press `r` and repeat.
3. user enters `interact`, opening the interactive session

Steps 2 and 3 require the user to know quite a bit about the program, certainly not as elegant as `interpreter`.  I would like to see better ways of doing this.